# Attach commands to TreeView in wpf using prism

Tags: wpf, treeview, prism, delegatecommand

How do I use a `DelegateCommand` in a `TreeView` to get the `Expanded` event?

Should I be using the `DelegateCommand` or is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are mentioning Prism, I assume you have a controller or ViewModel attached to the view containing your TreeView...

That being the case, expose a boolean property IsExpanded

```
    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isExpanded)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
                //  Apply custom logic here...
            }
        }
    }
```

Now to hook this property up to the TreeView, you need to apply the following style in the TreeView's resources (or further up the Visual tree as appropriate)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

NB: You can also use a similar technique to hook up the IsSelected property - also very useful!!

Comment: Actually, in Prism that would look like:
...
public
  property IsExpanded: Boolean; notify;
...

No need to manually raise the PropertyChanged event with Prism.

Comment: That's incorrect.  You still need to raise the PropertyChanged notifier.  Prism does not change the behavior of WPF.

Comment: i added the propeties but it does not seem to work. Am i missing anything

Comment: It's difficult to guess what you may have missed - perhaps if you post where you have got, thus far? Also - have a read of this codeproject article on the WPF treeview control... it has helped me no end :) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx